# Is there a way to group Mongo data or do I need to do it in node/javascript?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a mongo collection.  Using the node.js driver:
    db.collection('notify').find();
Returns:

```
{ _id: '1376179201714-user102',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'Training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training3 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user103',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training2 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user104',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training5 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user133',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training1 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test2@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user134',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training2 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test2@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user135',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training4 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test2@test.com' ] }      
{ _id: '1376179201714-user203',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training1 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test3@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user204',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'Training2 is past due!', 
  message: 'Card maker, updating member info is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test3@test.com' ] }  
{ _id: '1376179201714-user205',  
  state: 'unread',  
  sender: 'Daily Notify Process',  
  datereceived: 1376179201714,  
  subject: 'training is past due!',  
  message: 'Training3 is past due!!!',  
  recipient: [ 'test3@test.com' ] }
```

Can I get it to look like this using mapreduce or group :

```
{recipient: ['test@test.com'],  
subject: 'Training is past due!',  
trainingblock: [  
    {message: 'Training3 is past due!!!'},  
    {message: 'Training2 is past due!!!'},   
    {message: 'Training5 is past due!!!'}  
    ]  
}  
{recipient: ['test@test.com'],  
subject: 'Training is past due!',  
trainingblock: [  
    {message: 'Training1 is past due!!!'},  
    {message: 'Training2 is past due!!!'},   
    {message: 'Training4 is past due!!!'}  
    ]  
}  
{recipient: ['test@test.com'],  
subject: 'Training is past due!',  
trainingblock: [  
    {message: 'Training1 is past due!!!'},  
    {message: 'Training2 is past due!!!'},  
    {message: 'Training3 is past due!!!'}  
    ]  
}
```

Or do I need to do it on the javascript/node side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I got without spending a ton of time on it. I don't know all of the requirements or how much your data varies. For instance, is recipient always a single value even though it's wrapped in an array? Regardless, it should be close enough for you to take the rest of the way.

It's grouping by the recipient and the subject, and just sending the message along. The reduce function creates the container, and for each message passed in, pushes the value into trainingblock.

```
db.collection.mapReduce(function() {
  var recipient = this.recipient[0];
  emit(recipient + "#" + this.subject, { message: this.message });
}, function(key, values) {
  var parts = key.split('#'),
      recipient = parts[0],
      subject = parts[1],
      block = { recipient: recipient, subject: subject, trainingblock: [] };

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      block.trainingblock.push({ message: values[i].message });
    }

    return block;
}, {out: { inline: 1 }});
```